# Some icons can't be placed on the bottom row in certain spots?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-icons

I'm currently having a very strange issue where certain icons can't be placed on the bottom row of my desktop and only in certain spots. Does anyone know what is going on?

[Video recording](https://youtu.be/Yc4j8LHv_NI)

**Update**

After playing around a bit I figured out that nothing can be placed on the bottom row of my desktop unless there is an icon above it. How strange. Surely this is a windows bug?

Comment: I would guess that your desktop icon spacing is so that the row itself does not fully fit on the screen (perhaps by one or 2 pixels not). The auto-arrange will try to arrange icons away from there, but if everything else is filled, they may stay...

Comment: Why does Superuser send my comment when I minimize my browser to test it...? Seems to be wrong, at least on Win7 the icon spacing adjusts automatically when I resize my screen (or taskbar), and there is no setting for it any more...